# How to restart a node app via pm2 and apply new config file?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node app running on Ubuntu 18.04. It was started using PM2 like so `pm2 start ./bin/web_server.js`

Under some circumstances the process runs out of memory throwing this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa18150 node::Abort() [node /path/to/app/bin/web_server.js]
 2: 0xa1855c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node /path/to/app/bin/web_server.js]
...
...
```

So I want to increase the heap size, which seems to be pretty straitforward for a node process. All one has to do is run it with the proper parameter set. e.g. `node --max-old-space-size=2048 ./bin/web_server.js`

Since I am already running my process using PM2, I want to pass the `max-old-space-size` parameter to node using PM2's `ecosystem.config.js` file. So I proceeded to add this config file into the APP's root directory. The contents are here:

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [{
        name: 'IntuListAPI',
        script: './bin/web_server.js',
        //watch: true,
        //watch_delay: 1000,
        max_memory_restart: '20G',
        node_args: [
            "--max-old-space-size=6144"
        ]
    }]
};
```

Now when I run `pm2 restart web_server` I expect PM2 to pick up the new config and restart my process with it. But it does not seem to work and I can't figure out why. Since it was originally started without `ecosystem.config.js`, is it now ignoring it?

To be sure, the process restarts just fine, it just doesn't restart with the new heap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further research, I learned that in order to accomplish this I had to delete my APP from pm2 and then restart it using the `ecosystem.config.js` file. These two commands is all I needed:

```
pm2 delete web_server
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js
```

The last command will start up `./bin/web_server.js` and apply all the specified parameters.